# Gradle Project sync Failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I newly installed Android studio 0.4.6 on windows 8.

On creating a new project or importing one i am getting the "Gradle Project sync failed".
I tried the following to no avail.

1. Invalidate caches/restart.
2. Delete .gradle from user home directory and let it auto download.
3. Delete all the .iml and .idea folders.
4. Downgraded to jdk 1.7.
5. Reduced heap size.
6. Completely uninstalled and deleted all files of AS and reinstalled.
7. Updated gradle-wrapper.properties to 1.10.Gave a local path to gradle and also build.gradle to 0.9+.

Still the same error "Gradle Project sync failed"
Does anybody know any other things I can try?

EDIT:

I removed the extra bracket from build.gradle and these are the new errors that i got.

```
14.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
        01:18:14.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.j
        ava:69)       
        01:18:14.522 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)

        01:18:14.529 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExe
        cuter.java:35)
        01:18:14.539 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        01:18:14.546 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        01:18:14.554 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecu
        ter.java:42)  
        01:18:14.564 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.ja
        va:52)        
        01:18:14.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        01:18:14.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.ja
        va:43)        
        01:18:14.586 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
        01:18:14.594 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecuto
        r.java:79)    
        01:18:14.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecuto
        r.java:63)    
        01:18:14.608 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:5
        1)            
        01:18:14.617 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
        01:18:14.625 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        01:18:14.634 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
        01:18:14.641 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
        01:18:14.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore
        .java:135)    
        01:18:14.662 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(Default
        TaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:95)
        01:18:14.669 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
        01:18:14.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        01:18:14.684 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        01:18:14.693 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        01:18:14.699 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        01:18:14.706 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        01:18:14.713 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        01:18:14.723 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        01:18:14.731 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        01:18:14.737 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        01:18:14.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        01:18:14.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        01:18:14.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.
        java:64)      
        01:18:14.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        01:18:14.774 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        01:18:14.783 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        01:18:14.792 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        01:18:14.799 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        01:18:14.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        01:18:14.813 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201
        )             
        01:18:14.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174
        )             
        01:18:14.832 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        01:18:14.839 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        01:18:14.846 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        01:18:14.854 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        01:18:14.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
        01:18:14.868 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        01:18:14.875 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        01:18:14.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        01:18:14.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        01:18:14.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        01:18:14.906 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        01:18:14.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        01:18:14.923 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
        01:18:14.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run c
        ommand:       
                C:\Users\shreZ~\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\aapt.exe package -v -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\shreZ~\AppData\Local\Android\android-st
        udio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioP
        rojects\MyApplication2\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAppli
        cation2\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.myapplication2.ap
        p --output-text-symbols C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\symbols\debug
        Error Code:
                -1073741816

        01:18:14.939 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
        01:18:14.948 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
        01:18:14.957 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(An
        notationProcessingTaskFactory.java:236)
        01:18:14.964 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(Annotat
        ionProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
        01:18:14.971 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(Anno
        tationProcessingTaskFactory.java:223)
        01:18:14.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(Annotat
        ionProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
        01:18:14.986 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
        01:18:14.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
        01:18:15.000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ja
        va:80)        
        01:18:15.007 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.j
        ava:61)       
        01:18:15.014 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 52 more
        01:18:15.025 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
                C:\Users\shreZ~\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\aapt.exe package -v -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\shreZ~\AppData\Local\Android\android-st
        udio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioP
        rojects\MyApplication2\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAppli
        cation2\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.myapplication2.ap
        p --output-text-symbols C:\Users\shreZ~\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\symbols\debug
        Error Code:
                -1073741816

        01:18:15.033 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:98)
        01:18:15.041 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:69)
        01:18:15.048 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:736)
        01:18:15.058 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder$processResources.call(Unknown Source)
        01:18:15.066 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.groovy:95)
        01:18:15.074 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:64)
        01:18:15.081 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        01:18:15.091 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 60 more
        01:18:15.100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
        01:18:15.109 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
        01:18:15.117 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
        01:18:15.127 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
        01:18:15.138 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 32.027 secs
```

Comment: Would you run gradlew.bat build --debug and post the detailed errors you see?

Comment: @user2713030 Here is my Detailed log report : http://txs.io/n0P

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, there's a syntax error in your **build.gradle** file: an extra closing brace at line 6. Delete that brace, resynchronize your project, and if there are still errors that you can't figure out, post your full **build.gradle** file in your question.

Comment: i removed the the extra bracket and re run the cmnd. Updated with new log.

Comment: You might need to provide the full new log.

Comment: That -1073741816 error is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61308. You can find advice on what to fix in the bug report, but in short, it's generally caused by a reference to a missing reference in one of your resource files. An invalid @string reference in a menu resource seems a common culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Click on Gradle -> Use local gradle distribution -> Select the exact location of your Gradle folder -> click apply then OK.

After that , if gradle sync still fails. Do a small little change in your build.gradle(Module:app) file (for example, put a space anywhere and remove it back). Studio will ask to syn your gradle file, Click on "Sync Now" on the top right corner of the screen.

This will sync your gradle properly.